# how to set path to the views (template) directory and to static files in node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I have created **layout.jade**, **navigation.jade**, and **index.jade**, and I want to glue them together.

In **server.js**, how do I

1. set the path to the views (template) directory, and
2. set the path to static files.

Is it required that `node_module` be placed in the folder that contains **server.js**?

Below is the code for **server.js**:

```
//create an app server
var express = require("express");
var server = express.createServer();

//set path to the views (template) directory
app.set('views', D:\#Programming\node.js\trial box\views);

//set path to static files
//how is the path to static files set?
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../public'));

//handle GET requests on /
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('index.jade', {title: 'web project'});
});

//listen on localhost:3000
app.listen(3000);
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This questions a little old, but I'll still leave an answer. You'll need to place your app.use(...  statement inside a callback function for app.configure() like so..

```
app.configure(function(){
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../public'));
});
```

Comment: app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

Answer (score -4):

You should use the `express` bin tool to bootstrap a project you'd get all that setup.
To install it:

```
sudo npm install express -g
```